# Move breadcrumb Block purely via local.xml

Tags: layout

I want to move the breadcrumb block purely using `local.xml`.

It needs to be moved from its default location to the content block somewhere for me to output.

Usually when moving blocks i would `unsetChild` and then `insert`, however, this is making the breadcrumb block appear twice and also its not actually moving it anywhere.

```
<reference name="root">
    <action method="unsetChild"><name>breadcrumbs</name></action>
    <reference name="content">
        <action method="insert"><child>breadcrumbs</child></action>
    </reference>
</reference>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a good exercise - a good chance to learn. Because a layout XML move in Magento 1 is really a composite operation (unser from original parent, add to new parent), debugging requires testing both conditions.

The `insert` is obviously working, as you are seeing the **breadcrumbs** block twice. That means that the `unsetChild` call is *not* working. This is almost always the result of one of two things: incorrect child alias or incorrect parent reference. In your case, it is the latter. This is the result of a custom (non-CE) theme; for example, the *enterprise/default* theme declares the **breadcrumbs** block in a `core/text_list` block named **breadcrumbs.container**.

Also, reference tags should not be nested. They *will* work when nested, but given that they operate against the global block list by name, it's not necessary.

Comment: Im not so sure it is as simple as this.  I am using magento CE and have created a theme.  This theme only inherits from the base CE theme.  I have grepped the base layout folder for breadcrumb and the only instance is where it is declared in page.xml as name="breadcrumbs" as="breadcrumbs".  Therefore i am referencing the correct block.  Also, the unset is working because, if i ommit the insert then the breadcrumbs dissapears.  But using the insert inserts it twice.  Further, it is not actually putting it inside the content block, but still inside root

Comment: It is also worth noting, that the issue only happens if i insert the block to the 'content' block.  I am doing this on a category page and if i insert into the product_list for example, then it works fine.  Only an issue with the content block.

Answer (score 1):

Actually breadcrumbs cannot be moved via XML because it has callout in root templates. For example:

```
        <div class="main-container col1-layout">
        <div class="main">
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('breadcrumbs') ?>
            <div class="col-main">
                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('global_messages') ?>
                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('content') ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: That shouldn't be a problem, if the child does not exist, `$this->getChildHtml()` will return an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

Try just add it without nested references:

```
<default>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="unsetChild"><name>breadcrumbs</name></action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="content">
        <action method="insert"><child>breadcrumbs</child></action>
    </reference>
</default>
```

or:

```
<default>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="unsetChild"><name>breadcrumbs</name></action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="page/html_breadcrumbs" name="breadcrumbs" as="breadcrumbs" template="page/html/breadcrumbs.phtml" />
    </reference>
</default>
```

Then call the "breadcrumbs" block in your template file.

Comment: No, that makes no difference to the behaviour

Answer (score 0):

May be the breadcrumbs blcok may have been set to different name or different handler so even if u insert it in default it is not moving .
u need to define it in the particular handler

```
<handler>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="unsetChild"><name>breadcrumbs</name></action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="page/html_breadcrumbs" name="breadcrumbs" as="breadcrumbs" template="page/html/breadcrumbs.phtml" />
    </reference>
</handler>
```